# NodeJS MySql db.query command always running last

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

In my simple code which uses NodeJS and Express Framework along with MySql as my database, I made a simple query to the database. This is shown below vvv

```
app.get('/getusers', (req, res) => {

    console.log('Start line')

    let sql = 'SELECT * FROM users';
    let query = db.query(sql, (err, results) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(results);
        res.send('Posts fetched...');
    });

    console.log('End line')

});
```

In the terminal, the code's output is as shown below vvv

```
Start line
End line
[
  RowDataPacket {
    id: 1,
    usnm: 'admin',
    pswd: 'securePassword'
  },
  RowDataPacket {
    id: 2,
    usnm: 'user',
    pswd: 'superSeurePassword'
  }
]
```

Why did the lines "Start line" and "End line" run first, then the `db.query` command run later?
How can I fix my code so that it runs in order?

Answer (score 0):

A database query is an asyncronous operation, meaning that you should await the result of the query:

```
const util = require('util');
const query = util.promisify(db.query).bind(db); // Make db.query able to be awaited

app.get('/getusers', async (req, res) => { // declare your function as 'async'

    console.log('Start line')

    let sql = 'SELECT * FROM users';

    // Convert your callback to an try/catch block, so we could catch the error
    try {
      const results = await query(sql) // Your results will be returned straight here
      console.log(results);
      res.send('Posts fetched...');
    } catch (err) { // If some error happens, it will be catched here
      throw err;
    }

    console.log('End line')

});
```

Comment: When I type this command, I don't get the usual query. What I mean is, I didn't get the results like seen in the example I gave above. I can't type it out here because it exceeds the character limit. Link to the output [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C2F00N7iG80pEu3lDol1HHAyLGROgIHf/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: What I set db as:

const mysql = require('mysql');

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '',
    database : 'personal'
});

db.connect((err) => {
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    console.log('MySqli Connected...');
});

Comment: I have updated the answer. `mysql` is a bit old and doesnt have support for `async/await` syntax, so we have to do it manually.

Comment: Sorry to trouble you but... [new error](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iLE94y-KQP3DA76pIeZJae8thsG5u2jt/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Added `.bind(db)` in the first line. Can you try again? Sorry Im not familiar with `mysql` library